# Rendering to Viewer Node in headless mode

Tags: scripting, node-editor, compositing-nodes, command-line

I'm running Blender 2.79:

```
/path/to/blender -b empty.blend -P script.py
```

With `script.py`:

```
import numpy as np
import bpy

x, y = 100, 100
print("rendering")
bpy.ops.render.render()
res = bpy.data.images['Viewer Node']
print(len(res.pixels[:]), x*y*4)
arr = np.array(res.pixels[:]).reshape((y, x, 4))
```

`empty.blend` is a simple scene (camera+cube+light) with render settings at 100px by 100px @ 100%, with compositing nodes:

[image]

I get an error because `res.pixels[:]` has length 262144 (= 256 * 256 * 4) when it should be 40000 (= 100 * 100 * 4). Moreover, `res.pixels[:]` is **all zeros**.

If I run Blender **without** `-b`, it works.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I have exactly the same issue..

Comment: @Fredriku73 Nope.